# Powershell Set Variable for winforms objects

Tags: powershell, winforms, new-object

I'm trying to define variables to winform object: $Textbox_serverDNS1,$Textbox_serverDNS2,$Textbox_serverDNS3

[image]

I'm trying to use this syntax, but it's now working:

```
for ($i=1; $i -le 3; $i++){
        Set-Variable -Name "TextBox_ServerDNS$($i)" -Value (New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.TextBox -Property @(Text = "10.10.10.$i")) -Scope Global
    }
```

any idea how can I define it in this way?

thanks,

Comment: What happens when you run your existing code? Do you get an error, does it silently fail, or does it do something other than what you expect (and what does it do in that case)?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing needed to fix your command is to replace `-Property @(Text = "10.10.10.$i")` with `-Property @{ Text = "10.10.10.$i" }`, i.e. **you need to pass a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) (`@{ ... }`) with property *name-value pairs* rather than an *array* (`@(...)`)**.

- The [`New-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object) show the `-Property` parameter as [`IDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IDictionary)(-interface)-typed, meaning that a *dictionary-like* object - such as `[hashtable]` instance - must be passed.

However, you can **streamline** your approach as follows:

```bash
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

1..3 | ForEach-Object {
  Set-Variable -Scope Global -Name "TextBox_ServerDNS$_" -Value (
    [System.Windows.Forms.TextBox] @{ Text = "10.10.10.$_" }
  )
}
```

Note the convenient ability to *cast* the hashtable to the target type, which implicitly constructs an instance (assuming a parameter-less constructor) and initializes its properties based on the hashtable's entries.

**Taking a step back**:

- Generally, it's **best to *avoid* global variables**, because they are *session-global*, i.e. they linger even after your script exits.
- **Instead of creating *individual variables*, it's preferable to construct a single *array* variable that stores the instances**; the following example uses the `$script:` scope instead of the global one:

```bash
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

# You can use indexing to access the individual text boxes later, 
# e.g. $textBoxArray[0]
$script:textBoxArray = 
  1..3 | ForEach-Object { [System.Windows.Forms.TextBox] @{ Text = "10.10.10.$_" } }
```

---

**Update**:

- It turns out that your true **intent was to change the text of *existing* `TextBox` instances**.
- This requires the use of [`Get-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-variable) in order to indirectly retrieve variable values, as shown below.

```bash
1..3 | ForEach-Object {
  (Get-Variable -ValueOnly -Name "TextBox_ServerDNS$_").Text = "10.10.10.$_"
}
```

Comment: tried all the answers.
the results are good in the property of the element, but it's not showing  anything in the form.

Comment: @AmirMatzas, your question is about storing newly created `TextBox` instances in distinct variables, and that is what this shows how to do, along with a potentially better alternative. Whether those instance show in the form (which requires _adding_ them to the form) is a different problem.

Comment: hi,
you are right,
i don't want to create new forms items,   i created them.
i just want to change the strings in their text element.
using the same loop. not set-variable but change the existing text inside them.
thanks.

Comment: @AmirMatzas, I see. Please see my update, which uses `Get-Variable` to retrieve the variable values indirectly.

Comment: thanks, it's just the thing I was looking for.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @AmirMatzas. Note that you can help future readers by clearly signaling which answer, if any, solved your problem, namely by [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/248777) it.

Answer (score -1):

How about something like this?

```
add-type -assembly presentationframework
1..3 | foreach-object {
  set-variable "TextBox_ServerDNS$_" $(
    $box = [windows.controls.textbox]::new()
    $box.text = "10.10.10.$_"
    $box
  )
}
```

I would double check to make sure you're loading the correct types/assemblies you need as well.

Comment: You accidentally posted a WPF solution, whereas the question is about WinForms. Apart from that, while your approach would work, it is more cumbersome than the OP's own attempt, which can be fixed by simply replacing `-Property @(Text = "10.10.10.$i")` with `-Property @{ Text = "10.10.10.$i" }`